# Getting exception while reading data from JSON RDD

Tags: json, apache-spark

While running following snippet of the code, I am getting exception. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
JavaDStream<String> newDstream= newlines.window(Durations.seconds(300),Durations.seconds(120));

newDstream.print(); //This prints perfectly
newDstream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        //Logger.debug("RDD received: {}",rdd.collect());
        Dataset<Row> df = sqlcontext.read().option("multiline", true).json(rdd);
        df.printSchema();
        df.show();
    }
});
```

Below is the output of df.printSchema

```
root
 |-- priceData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- close: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- high: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- low: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- open: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- volume: string (nullable = true)
 |-- symbol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

and here is the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.util.SerializableConfiguration cannot be cast 
    to [B at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:81) at
org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108) at 
org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can I know what you are asking? Comment code or complete code?

Comment: the code that you put in your first comment -  i bet it belongs to the question too, so why not add it there?

Comment: I was not able to do it since I was getting formatting error and I couldn't resolve it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: were you able to solve this?